# How to disable automaximize in 16.04?

Tags: unity, 16.04, maximized

The automaximize option makes use of the windows almost impossible. every time i want to move window out of the way it will automaximize, when I touch the title bar, while maximized, in order to move it away, it will un-maximize it and place it in the original position and so on... making it impossible to move it out of the way.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open Unity Tweak tool.
2. Go to **Window Manager** section
3. Click on **Window Snapping**
4. Under **Behaviour**, There is screen. On the top of it, There is a pop-up selection menu.
5. Select **Do Nothing** from that menu.
6. You can repeat selecting **Do Nothing** for other sides if you want.

If you don't have Unity Tweak Tool installed, install it with

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

command in a terminal

Here is a screenshot of that settings window

[image: tweak settings]

Comment: That does the trick when *dragging* a window. Is there a similar option for *resizing* windows? If I resize by dragging the top edge of the window all the way to the top of the screen, the window still gets maximised despite 'Do Nothing' selected for that edge.