# Windows still locking in place after disabling snapping in Compiz config

Tags: compiz, window

I turned off all window snapping in Compiz config, but there is still this annoying behavior where windows lock to both the top and bottom of my monitor(s) once the browser top hits the monitor top.

What settings might be responsible for this locking behavior?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, running 16.04, the only solution that worked was:

**Compiz > Window Management > Resize Window > General** uncheck **Maximize Vertically if screen edge hit**

Answer (score 1):

Three answers that a likely quite helpful, particularly for the maximizing behaviour:

- **`unity-tweak-tool`** - https://askubuntu.com/a/819246/210504
- **`ccsm`** - https://askubuntu.com/a/46780/210504
- **`gconf-editor`** - https://askubuntu.com/a/72480/210504

Comment: Thank you , tried the ccsm and gconf to no avail.. installing unity tweek now

Comment: Did you disable maximizing from `ccsm` --> Window Managements -> Grid -> Corners/Edges -> Top Edge? 
This answer won't solve the Top/Bottom locking as of yet, trying to find a solution now.

Comment: Found the culprit!   was in compiz after all.    Compiz > Resize Window > General > Maximize Vertically if screen edge hit.
Quite specific....
tyvm for the efforts

Comment: @elendee: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)